# Would the solution to this counting problem be correct?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

Suppose we have an inexhaustible amount of black beads, white beads, and $n-k$ other colors of beads (red, blue, green, etc., etc.) (By "inexhaustible" it is meant that "at least $k$ black beads", "$k$ white beads", and "at least one bead of each of the $n-k$ other colors".)

How many ways/orders can we pick $n$ beads such that exactly $k$ beads are black or white and the remaining $n-k$ beads have no repeated colors?

To my understanding we can find how many different orders by doing the following.
For the exactly $k$ white or black beads we have ${n \choose k}$ different ways to pick them. and $2^k$ ways to order them so ${n \choose k} 2^k$. For the second part to have no repeated other colors we would put $(n-k)$ choices for the first non black or white bead $(n-k-1)$ choices for the second, etc. bringing us to the falling factorial in terms of $n$ and $k$. so our answer would be ${n \choose k} 2^k (n-k)_k$ different ways. Is this correct? Would this be using a product principle for counting?

Comment: It is not clear what an arrangement of the objects you are counting looks like.  Are these beads you are picking all jumbled into a pile where order within the pile doesn't matter?  Are they beads laid out in a line with a clear beginning and a clear end and order within the line matters?  Are they placed on a bracelet and rotations and flips of a bracelet counts as the same bracelet?  On a [necklace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) and only rotations count as the same but flips might count as different?

Comment: As for your attempt, it is almost correct for the interpretation that the beads were to be laid in a line with a clear beginning and a clear end (*which is unclear if this is even the correct interpretation*) however it makes a mistake with the falling factorial.  Think a bit longer on that part... why $n-k$?  Why $k$?  How many beads in total were we needing to pick and how many of the colorful (nonwhite/nonblack) beads were going to be used?  $k$ of them?  Or all $n-k$ of them?

Comment: If you *were* to try to tackle the question of counting bracelets or necklaces, suppose one of the colorful colors available was gold.  Since we will always use exactly one gold bead, you can use that as a reference point.  You can treat the gold bead like you might a clasp, letting the gold bead act like the beginning and end of the line and work with it like you would the problem of the line.  Further, to deal with reflections, assuming $n-k\geq 3$ you can imagine if two of the other beads were silver and bronze and ensure the bracelet is laid so gold silver bronze are always in that order.